# Using vhdl code and c++ in amazon f1 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a program written in c++ and it runs on the ec2 machine (Amazon - AWS).

My program calculates some calculation between one matrix vs a lot of matrices.

It takes a lot of time and I want to reduce the calculation time.

I know to write (a little... ) in VHDL, so I want to combine my program and an FPGA. And because of my program runs on ec2 I thought to use with  f1 instance too.

The problem is that I know how to write in c++, and VHDL but I don't know how to use f1 instance and more important, I don't know how to combine between them.

Any help will be appreciated,

Eliya

Comment: This is not a programming question. This is not the Amazon support website.

Comment: See https://github.com/aws/aws-fpga